# Platform independent Connection String for EXCEL in java

Tags: java, excel

Is there a PLATFORM INDEPENDENT connection string for EXCEL file in java. jdbc:odbc is platform dependent. Is there anything else ??

Comment: I sang aware that odbc was available on other platforms...could be wrong though....

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/585719/JDBC/databases/java-excel-JDBC) post you could see an example of using a connection string without the ODBC. I suppose this is what you are looking for...

```
Class.forName("com.hxtt.sql.excel.ExcelDriver").newInstance();  

String url = "jdbc:Excel:///E:/JavaWithExcel/Feedback.xlsx";  
String sql = "select * from [Sheet1]";  

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");  

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
System.out.println(con);  
System.out.println(stmt);  

stmt.close();  
con.close();
```

Anyway, you have to understand that the connection string is always specific to the underlying environment. It could depend on the operating system, on the file system or something else... I would just use different configuration files for each environment.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Please include a brief description in your answer of what the link is telling us.  Suppose the link were offline or changed, then we would have no idea what you are telling us.